# org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockMissingException in hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata, cascading

I get the below exception in Hadoop job. I'm not able to figure out the cause of this exception. Can you help me resolving this error? Why do we get this error?

Exception stack trace:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: blk_6488469967470272993_1110 file=/media/ephemeral0/hadoop-root/5614861051_themeToProductsPipe_F832FB7243E64F41892F20744AF6A0B7/part-00054
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSClient.java:3158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSClient.java:2940)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.read(DFSClient.java:3107)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.(SequenceFile.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.(SequenceFile.java:1543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.(SequenceFile.java:1538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader.(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.getRecordReader(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:64)
    at cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputFormat$1.operate(MultiInputFormat.java:253)
    at cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputFormat$1.operate(MultiInputFormat.java:248)
    at cascading.util.Util.retry(Util.java:762)
    at cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputFormat.getRecordReader(MultiInputFormat.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$3.run(Child.java:205)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the client wasn't able to hit the data node(s) that contain the block on time. That could be by a network issue or because the data nodes are too busy to respond or they are down.

The exception is not enough to track the root cause.